# number_format issue with decimal

Tags: php, mysql, number-formatting

am trying to display decimal number from database in coma seperated format....
e.g 1000000 to be 1,000,000

am currently using **number_format() function**

but when i make some calculation it gets messy....
e.g **it display 900000.00 to 9.00** instead of **900000.00=> 900,000.00**

any help??

here is my code

```
if($amount==$fee){
 $status='Huna DENI';

 }

elseif($amount<$fee){
$debt=$fee-$amount;
$status='Una DENI la:'.' '.number_format($debt,2,".",",").'
 '.'<font     color="#003399">'.'TSH'.'</font>';
                        }
```

Comment: `number_format()` should be used only for presentation, not calculation

Comment: see the line on your code with `$debt=$fee-$amount;` then you used `$debt['amount']`, shouldn't it be `$debt` only? if not, how would `$debt['amount']` have a value? (in `$debt=$fee-$amount;`)

Comment: What are the value and type of `$debt['amount']`? You can do `var_dump($debt['amount']);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$debt['amount']` while your declared variable is `$debt` so you code should look like

```
$status='Una DENI la:'.' '.number_format($debt,2,".",",").'
```

Comment: This indeed. Short explanation: (`$debt['amount']` when $debt is a scalar means: `$debt` is cast to string, `'amount'` is cast to `int`, `$debt['amount']` becomes `$debt[0]` which for a string means _"the first character"_, which is `9`, so that's the value that will be formatted).

Comment: yeah that's it i mixied it .....thenx

Comment: @internally1 you welcome, don't forget to accept the answer for help people in the future with similar problems